# How to check for null/empty/whitespace values with a single test in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I would like to check an input (parameter) of a stored procedure if it has many spaces and empty, not just 1 space like so:
`'   '`  '.
I tried :

```
IF column IS NULL or TRIM(column IS NULL) THEN RAICE NOTICE 'input is empty spaces';
END IF;
```

But the spaces input still passes through.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE()` here:

```sql
IF
    COALESCE(column, '') ~ '^\s*$'
THEN
    RAICE NOTICE 'input is empty spaces';
END IF;
```

The pattern `^\s*$` will match zero or more whitespace characters.  The outer call to `COALESCE()` replaces `NULL` column values with empty string, which will match the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM(column IS NULL)` should result in an error, because `column is null` yields a `boolean` and `trim()` doesn't work on boolean values.

Note that `trim()` will return an *empty* string if the input is only blank, not `null` (an empty string `''` is something different than `null`)

You can shorten the whole test to a single expression:

```
if nullif(trim(column), '') is null then ...
```

Comment: yeah i made a typo with the TRIM(column is NULL) , i used your method and it worked , thanks a lot.